# Vue form Wizard prevent back step

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

we are working with injection of dynamic components by server response, but once the user has approved a step, we will prevent him from going back to the steps he has already approved.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
<div>
  <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete">
    <tab-content v-for="tab in tabs"
                v-if="!tab.hide"
                :key="tab.title"
                :title="tab.title"
                :icon="tab.icon">
      <component :is="tab.component"></component>
    </tab-content>
  </form-wizard>
 </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
Vue.component('step1', {
 template:` <div> My first tab content <br>
             </div>`
 }
)
Vue.component('step2', {
 template:`<div>  My second tab content </div>`
})
Vue.component('step3', {
 template:`<div>  My third tab content </div>`
})
Vue.component('step4', {
template:`<div> Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple </div>`
})
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
    return {
    tabs: [{title: 'Personal details', icon: 'ti-user', component: 'step1'}, 
    {title: 'Is Logged In?', icon: 'ti-settings', component: 'step2', hide: false}, 
    {title: 'Additional Info', icon: 'ti-location-pin', component: 'step3'},
    {title: 'Last step', icon: 'ti-check', component: 'step4'},
    ],
  }
 },
 methods: {
  onComplete: function(){
      alert('Yay. Done!');
   }
  }
})
```

but we have not found answers in the documentation if suddenly someone has had this problem and can tell us how to solve it, I would appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: I believe this is what validate-on-back and on-validate are responsible for.

Comment: @EstusFlask thank, you and we try :validateOnBack="true" but not works or we are used but?

Comment: What about on-validate?

Comment: @EstusFlask we not use, only before-change on tab, and validateOnBack on wizard

Comment: That's a good reason to start doing this. I mentioned them both together.

Answer (score 2):

> Once the user has approved a step, we will prevent him from going back
> to the steps he has already approved.

Validate going forward, then simply remove the back button.

I did some tests and the beforeTabSwitch doesn't fire if going backwards `props.prevTab()`, shame as you could then do it in the validate call.

Here is an example, which validates going forward and removes the Previous button and prevents navigating via the header (wizard-step).

```js
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
Vue.component('step1', {
  template: ` <div> My first tab content</div>`,
  data: () => ({
    name: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    validate() {
      // change `true` to things checked on model, beyond scope of question
      this.$emit('on-validate', this.$data, true)
      return true
    }
  }
})
Vue.component('step2', {
  template: `<div>  My second tab content </div>`,
  data: () => ({
    logged_in_yada: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.$emit('on-validate', this.$data, true)
      return true
    }
  }
})
Vue.component('step3', {
  template: `<div>  My third tab content </div>`,
  data: () => ({
    additional_info: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.$emit('on-validate', this.$data, true)
      return true
    }
  }
})
Vue.component('step4', {
  template: `<div> Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple </div>`,
  data: () => ({
    last_step: ''
  }),
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.$emit('on-validate', this.$data, true)
      return true
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      tabModel: {},
      tabs: [{
          title: 'Personal details',
          icon: 'ti-user',
          component: 'step1'
        },
        {
          title: 'Is Logged In?',
          icon: 'ti-settings',
          component: 'step2',
          hide: false
        },
        {
          title: 'Additional Info',
          icon: 'ti-location-pin',
          component: 'step3'
        },
        {
          title: 'Last step',
          icon: 'ti-check',
          component: 'step4'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onComplete: function() {
      alert('Yay. Done!');
    },
    validateStep(name) {
      return this.$refs[name][0].validate()
    },
    mergeTabModel(model, isValid) {
      if (isValid) {
        // merging each step model into the final model
        this.tabModel = Object.assign({}, this.tabModel, model)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/lykmapipo/themify-icons/master/css/themify-icons.css">


<div id="app">
  <div>
    <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete">
      <wizard-step slot-scope="props" slot="step" :tab="props.tab" :transition="props.transition" :index="props.index">
      </wizard-step>
      <tab-content v-for="tab in tabs" v-if="!tab.hide" :key="tab.title" :title="tab.title" :icon="tab.icon" :before-change="()=>validateStep(tab.component)">
        <component :is="tab.component" :ref="tab.component" @on-validate="mergeTabModel"></component>
      </tab-content>
      <template slot="footer" scope="props">
        <div class="wizard-footer-left">
          <!-- remove previous button -->
          <!-- <wizard-button v-if="props.activeTabIndex > 0 && !props.isLastStep" @click.native="props.prevTab()" :style="props.fillButtonStyle">Previous</wizard-button> -->
        </div>
        <div class="wizard-footer-right">
          <wizard-button @click.native="props.nextTab()" class="wizard-footer-right finish-button" :style="props.fillButtonStyle">{{props.isLastStep ? 'Done' : 'Next'}}</wizard-button>
        </div>
      </template>
    </form-wizard>

    <pre>{{ tabModel }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone, it works, and i have add the next the button and the step in my import, import { FormWizard, TabContent, WizardButton, WizardStep } from 'vue-form-wizard'

Comment: np nice, don't forget to accept if it works :), yeah have to do it like above to get it working for SO, better to import properly

Answer (score 1):

using `refs`

```
this.$refs.wizardFirst.displayPrevButton = false
```

```
"vue-form-wizard": "0.8.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS instead:

```
.vue-form-wizard .wizard-nav-pills a, .vue-form-wizard .wizard-nav-pills li{
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Although that will prevent the clicks on various buttons, the Back button from the browser will still work and send the user to a previous page/state, right?